# How to use jQuery Plugin in Electron Renderer Process?

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I'm making webview app by Electron.

When i want to use this plugin, can not load.
http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/

jQuery is working collect, but plugin in not.

how to load plugin in electron ?

code is below.

app.js(main process)

```
app.on('ready', function() {
   mainWindow = new MainWindow();
   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
   width: 1480,
   height: 800,
   preload: __dirname + '/index.js',
   "zoom-factor": 1.0
  });
  mainWindow.loadUrl('https://example.com');
  mainWindow.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', function(event, url) {
  shell.openExternal(url);
  event.preventDefault();
   });
mainWindow.webContents.on('closed', function() {
mainWindow = null;
app.quit();});
ipc.on('loadurl', function(event, args) {
 mainWindow.window.loadUrl(args.url);
 mainWindow.window.focus();
});
```

index.js(render process)

```
var remote = require('remote');
var app = remote.require('app');
var ipc = require('ipc');
var myScript = require('./lib/myScript');
var BrowserWindow = remote.require('browser-window');
  window.onload = function(){
    myScript.sumeFunc();
  };
```

myScript.js(using jquery plugin)

```
var remote = require('remote');
var $ = jQuery = remote.require('./jquery-2.1.4.min');
require('./jquery.selection');
var myScript = {
someFunc: function () {
'use strict';

var toolBarSelector = '.chatSendTool';
var chatTextAreaSelector = '#_chatText';

function getContents() {
  var selected = $(chatTextAreaSelector).selection(); //this is jquery plugin

  if (selected) return selected;
  return $(chatTextAreaSelector).val();
}
}};
```

error is below

Underlying error: jQuery requires a window with a document

Comment: So how do we know what happened if you don't provide any error messages, code, etc?

Answer (score 2):

In your `myScript.js` try replacing:

```
var $ = jQuery = remote.require('./jquery-2.1.4.min');
```

with:

```
var $ = global.jQuery = require('./jquery-2.1.4.min');
```

I don't know why you were trying to do a remote require of jQuery.